# Sharepoint Directory Permissions And Admin Override

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I need to put together a folder where all users will submit their timesheets, but they can only see and edit their own. I want 3 admins who can see and edit everything in that folder.

I've spent about 20 working hours on this, and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've created custom groups, I've messed with list settings, user permissions, group permissions, I've looked at countless tutorials. Is this even possible to achieve without separate folders?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a folder for each user and give the user contribute permissions to it, and the admins should have contribute permissions on the root folder.